# Сompatible-screens в манифесте

Tags: android, android-manifest

Нужно ли пользоваться тегом `<compatible-screens>` в манифесте и указывать там все экраны, которые будет поддерживать мое приложение ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [офф.документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) есть ясный и однозначный ответ на ваш вопрос:

> Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and densities.

все это значит, что параметр следует указывать в крайних случаях, когда поддержка какого-то типоразмера экрана решительно невозможна.

Данный параметр применяется не для того, чтобы указать экраны, на которых приложение будет работать (хотя фактически указывается именно это), а только для того, чтобы исключить экраны, на которых оно точно не будет работать, если такие существуют.
Если приложение может работать на всех экранах - перечислять все типы не нужно, нужно просто проигнорировать этот параметр в манифесте.

Comment: Спасибо! Видел не раз, как перечисляют много разных экранов в манифесте, но зачем так - не знал.